# Handle object with properties on onChangeText event in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in react native and don't know how to handle current case and I already spend a lot of time searching for solution. I Have  following constructor:

```js
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    newNote: { title: '', description: '', dateToRead: null },
    modalVisible: false
  };
}
```

How can I save value on `onChangeText` event in TextInput? And is it correct handling of properties in react native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to handle the TextInput data

```
<TextInput
  onChange={(event) =>
  this.setState({newNote: {...this.state.newNote,
  title: event.nativeEvent.text}}
  )}
  value={this.state.newNote.title}
/>
```

or

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => 
    this.setState({newNote: {...this.state.newNote,description: text}}
  )}
  value={this.state.newNote.description}
/>
```

Comment: thanks, it works for me, but what approach is better? And is it ok to handle data in this way in react native?

Comment: They both for react native and They are equal You can use any